# Что если два потока одновременно попытаются использовать один Connection к DB

Tags: java, многопоточность, postgresql

Что произойдет если два потока одновременно возьмут 1 инстанс объекта `java.sql.Connection` и попытаются сделать по нему транзакцию к базе PostgresSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут скорее всего вопрос не в самой базе, а в JDBC драйвере.

Согласно https://stackoverflow.com/a/1531103/3978990:

> Если драйвер JDBC соответствует спецификации, то технически да, объект
>   является потокобезопасным, но вам следует избегать совместного
>   использования соединений между потоками, поскольку активность в
>   соединении будет означать, что только один поток сможет делать что
>   угодно в этом `Connection` единовременно.
>
> Вы должны использовать пул соединений (например,
>   Apache Commons DBCP), чтобы гарантировать, что каждый поток получает
>   свой собственный `Connection`.